# What does this eclipse symbol mean?

Tags: eclipse, symbols

i can't seem to find this symbol in the Eclipse documentation, and i'm no expert in using Eclipse.

Can anyone explain to me what it means?

The symbol:
[Eclipse symbol http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/4489/eclipsesymbol.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/4489/eclipsesymbol.png)

It's the arrow that confuses me. Can it be a shared resource?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a SVN decoration for an External Folder

Check Eclipse Preferences
"Team" - "SVN" - "Label Decorations"

You can see a list of Decorations and their meanings